# Ask jboss if it has a web method?

Tags: .net, web-services, jboss

We have our web services written in Java running on JBoss.  Our website is written in .Net 3.5.  We've run into an issue where if a web service has a change, sometimes it breaks the website, and they end up having to be deployed at the same time.

Right now I changed a web service, and the website code has been changed to match.  The old service method is still around.  But, if one of our developers updates his website code and not his service code, it breaks, because the old service doesn't have that method.

So, is it possible for the website, at runtime, to ask jboss, "Do you support web method X?  No?  Then let's use Y instead."

This way, the website doesn't blow up on developer boxes and no one throws empty candy wrappers at me anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just parse the WSDL and find out if the method is still there. It will work with JBoss, .NET or any WebService written in any programming language.

Comment: Does this mean I need to manually pull down the wsdl at runtime and run an xpath query against it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english, I speak spanish.

You can publish the services in a [UDDI](http://uddi.org/pubs/uddi-tech-wp.pdf) server, and search the correct service for each situation. While it is an elegant solution, maybe is kill a fly with a bomb.